# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I get this error when calling the procedure. I am trying to do this practice.

Create a procedure called find_region_and_currency to fetch and return the currency and region in which a country is located.
Pass COUNTRY_NAME as an IN parameter and use a user-defined record as an OUT parameter that returns the country name, its region and currency.

I tried old answer from here but I didnt do it. Could you please help me?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE traveler_assistance_package
IS

TYPE country_rec IS RECORD (
    country_name COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE,
    region COUNTRIES.REGION_ID%TYPE,
    currency COUNTRIES.CURRENCY_CODE%TYPE);
PROCEDURE find_region_and_currency
(p_country_name   IN COUNTRIES.country_name%TYPE,
p_country_rec     OUT country_rec);
END traveler_assistance_package;
CREATE OR REPLACE package body traveler_assistance_package 
IS
PROCEDURE find_region_and_currency 
(p_country_name   IN countries.country_name%TYPE,
p_country_rec     OUT country_rec)
IS
BEGIN 
SELECT country_name, region_id, currency_code INTO p_country_rec
FROM COUNTRIES
where COUNTRY_NAME = p_country_name;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Country Name:'||p_country_rec.country_name ||  
  'Region:' || p_country_rec.region || 
  'Currency:' || p_country_rec.currency);
END;
END traveler_assistance_package;
```

Comment: since the error occurs when you try to call the procedure, it would be helpful to show the code that does the call.

Comment: I am calling package like this "begin
 traveler_assistance_package.find_region_and_currency('Republic of Bolivia');
end" because 'Republic of Bolivia' is my in parameter. Then I get wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FIND_REGION_AND_CURRENCY' error.

Comment: Well ..the procedure has two parameters, and you're only passing one.  Seems like the meaning of the error is pretty clear.  Littlefoot's answer shows an example of how to call the procedure with two parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post what went wrong (which part of code); anyway, here you go.

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table countries
  2    (country_name    varchar2(20),
  3     region_id       varchar2(20),
  4     currency_code   varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into countries values ('Croatia', 'A', 'kn');

1 row created.
```

Package:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE traveler_assistance_package
  2  IS
  3    TYPE country_rec IS RECORD (
  4      country_name COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME%TYPE,
  5      region COUNTRIES.REGION_ID%TYPE,
  6      currency COUNTRIES.CURRENCY_CODE%TYPE);
  7    PROCEDURE find_region_and_currency
  8      (p_country_name   IN COUNTRIES.country_name%TYPE,
  9       p_country_rec     OUT country_rec);
 10  END traveler_assistance_package;
 11  /

Package created.
```

Package body:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE package body traveler_assistance_package
  2  IS
  3    PROCEDURE find_region_and_currency
  4      (p_country_name   IN countries.country_name%TYPE,
  5       p_country_rec     OUT country_rec)
  6    IS
  7    BEGIN
  8      SELECT country_name, region_id, currency_code INTO p_country_rec
  9      FROM COUNTRIES
 10      where COUNTRY_NAME = p_country_name;
 11
 12      --dbms_output.put_line('Printing from FIND_REGION_AND_CURRENCY');
 13      --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Country Name:'||p_country_rec.country_name ||
 14      --  ' Region:' || p_country_rec.region ||
 15      --  ' Currency:' || p_country_rec.currency);
 16    END;
 17  END traveler_assistance_package;
 18  /

Package body created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_out traveler_assistance_package.country_rec;
  3  begin
  4    traveler_assistance_package.find_region_and_currency ('Croatia', l_out);
  5
  6    dbms_output.put_line('Printing from anonymous PL/SQL block');
  7    dbms_output.put_line(l_out.country_name ||', '|| l_out.currency);
  8  end;
  9  /
Printing from anonymous PL/SQL block
Croatia, kn

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Calling like this --> begin
 traveler_assistance_package.find_region_and_currency('Republic of Bolivia');
end                                                                                                                          
 then I get                                                                                         ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FIND_REGION_AND_CURRENCY'

Comment: Of course. You declared it to accept **two** parameters, but you passed only one (Republic of Bolivia). You're missing the OUT parameter.

Comment: But I want to call with One parameter (Republic of bolivia)  and returns the country name, its region and currency. How is this possible? btw thank you for your help :)

Comment: @ezgi: The procedure *is* returning the data. Only, it seems you are desperately trying to avoid to use it. As you can see, Littlefoot only calls it with one IN parameter (Republic of bolivia) and gets the desired data in the OUT parameter. If for some reason you don't want an OUT parameter, then make the procedure a function with only the IN parameter and RETURN the record. It doesn't make much of a difference, however. Again, you'll have to accept what the function returns.

Comment: The fact is: your assignment says: "Pass COUNTRY_NAME as an IN parameter and **use a user-defined record as an OUT parameter** that returns the country name etc." so ... BTW you're welcome.